# VBA code for if like multiple criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a Excel function in VBA to check if a string contains certain criteria.

I can get it to work if I write it the long-winded way:

```
If code Like "*ABB*" Or code Like "*ABC* Or code Like "*ABE*" Then ...
```

But I have lots of criteria (15 now, but may increase in the future), so was hoping I could write them in an array instead, e.g.

```
Criteria = Array("*ABB*","*ABC*","*ABE*")
```

I'm just stuggling with the next stage; some way of checking if `code` is is part of `Criteria`.

I've been searching online, and can't find anything similar.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar problem today, and wrote a simple function to provide some [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) to an otherwise tedious approach to testing a series of like expressions.

```vb
If LikeAny(code, "*ABB*", "*ABC*", "*ABE*") Then...
```

To use this function, just add the following code to a standard module:

```
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : LikeAny
' Author    : Adam Waller
' Date      : 3/14/2023
' Purpose   : Returns true if strTest is LIKE any of the array of expressions.
'           : (Short ciruits to first matching expression)
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'
Public Function LikeAny(strTest As String, ParamArray varLikeThis()) As Boolean
    Dim lngCnt As Long
    For lngCnt = 0 To UBound(varLikeThis)
        If strTest Like varLikeThis(lngCnt) Then
            LikeAny = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next lngCnt
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an array for the criteria and loop in each field. A function returning a boolean should be easier to read and maintain.

```
Public Function Contains(ByVal code As String) As Boolean

    Dim Criteria As Variant
        Criteria = Array("*ABB*", "*ABC*", "*ABE*")

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(Criteria) To UBound(Criteria)
        If code Like Criteria(i) Then
            Contains = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

To call it:

```
Debug.Print Contains("WWABB")
'True
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like looping through the array to find the criteria would work as follows:

```
Sub foo()
code = "BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST"
'set the variable code
Criteria = Array("ABB", "ABC", "BCD")
'array of criteria
For i = LBound(Criteria) To UBound(Criteria) 'loop through array
    If InStr(code, Criteria(i)) > 0 Then MsgBox "Found criteria " & Criteria(i) 'if found msgbox
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Yours is a rather strange request because `*abc*` can return a very wide range of unexpected results, more so if used with `Like`, and then multiplied by 15, possibly more. On the other hand, if the `Code` values you have are rather well controlled `Like` probably has no greater meaning than "case insensitive". This is the presumption I have made in the solution I have suggested below. However, it would work with `Like` just the same.

The other thing I found strange is that you should have 15 (or more) different criteria which all need to be treated in the same manner. More likely, you should have need to treat results differently. Therefore I have built the test into a function which returns the sequential number of the match found.  If the following matches are acceptable, "ABC,DEF,LMN,RST,MIN,MAX,SDR,USA" and the `Code` contains "ABC" (or "abc" or "Abc" etc) the function returns `1` because the match is the first criterion in the list. It returns 0 if no match was found.

The code below consists of the function itself and an example of how you might call it.

```
Private Sub Call_Qualifier()

    Dim Match As Integer

    Match = Qualifier("This is my lmn trial code")
    Select Case Match
        Case 1
            Debug.Print """ABC"" was found"
        Case 2
            Debug.Print """DEF"" was found"
        Case 3
            Debug.Print """LMN"" was found"
        Case 0
            Debug.Print "No match was found"
    End Select
End Sub
Function Qualifier(ByVal Code As String) As Integer
    ' 12 Jan 2018
    ' return 0 if not found

    Dim Fun As Integer                      ' function return value
    Dim Crits() As String

    Crits = Split("ABC,DEF,LMN,RST,MIN,MAX,SDR,USA", ",")
    For Fun = UBound(Crits) To 0 Step -1
        If InStr(1, Code, Crits(Fun), vbTextCompare) Then Exit For
    Next Fun
    Qualifier = Fun + 1
End Function
```